# Blank Output after connecting with ADO.NET

Tags: ado.net, c#-2.0

I am having a problem with the connection string, connecting with ADO.NET

I have tried all combinations of arguments in the connection string.

It is just giving a blank output. What is the correct format?

I have not used USERID and PWD options because I have chosen windows authentication and not SQL authentication.

Comment: Please add more information. What connection string do you have?What error message are you getting?

Comment: The fact that you *have chosen windows authentication* suggests that you are using SQL Server, not MySQL. Is that right?

Comment: Yes. Im not 100% sure, but I would suppose that its right.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what you try but i think link help you.
http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: yes.. here are the details... the conncetion string is "Database=Databasename;Integrated Security=SSPI;Server=(local)"

Comment: The problem is no error message is displayed. It just gives a blank output.

Answer (score 0):

The correct format when using Windows Auth on localhost is like this:

```
Data Source=.;Application Name=AppName;Initial Catalog=DbName;Integrated Security=True
```

AppName and the Application Name clause are optional. DbName is the name of your database.

What gives a blank output? Have you walked through the code with a debugger? Have you looked at the issued T-SQL with SQL Profiler?